# Automatically add values before and after a value in a Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a library of flags online and would like to have a client-foolproof solution for adding flags.

Right now my function looks like this:

```
=image("http://www.website.com/flags/us.png", 3)
```

But I would like to just write "us" and the let the functions add this before:

```
=image("http://www.website.com/flags/
```

And this after:

```
.png", 3)
```

is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with function CONCATENATE to combine the strings. Assume the word us is in A1, you can add below forumla to B1,

```
=IMAGE(CONCATENATE("http://www.website.com/flags/",A1,".png"), 3)
```

You can also use function CONCAT too, but it is less useful as it only accepts two strings as parameters.

Comment: I copied and pasted your function (changing the URL to the correct path), but only get a "error: Not a number:"

Comment: fixed. please use comma instead of plus

Comment: This works perfectly! Is there a way to apply it to a column so that it is automatically added to the actual cell? S the same cell that I write "us" will be the same cell as the flag appears?

Comment: In my knowledge it is not possible with formula but it is possible with script in the script manager with `onEdit`. A sample is here, http://www.how2guru.com/archives/how-to-google-spreadsheet-trigger/